# How to align 2 arrays without temporary arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have 2 arrays that I need to align lines. I prepare the 'control' array which has the info on how to align arrays and then I do it, with help of temp arrays.

See in picture the arrays and result as aligned arrays:

[image]

Here is the code that I use, as MCVE:

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
      System.Math,
      System.Generics.Defaults,
      System.Generics.Collections;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

      TSide = (sLeft, sRight, sBoth);

      TData = record
        DataID: integer;
        DataName: string;
        BlankLine: boolean;
      end;

      TCtrlData = record
        Side: TSide;
        Idx_l: integer;
        Idx_r: integer;
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;
      aLeft, aRight, aLeft_tmp, aRight_tmp: TArray<TData>; // main and temp arrays
      aCtrl: TArray<TCtrlData>; // control array with instructions o nhow to align lines

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure PrepareData;
    begin
      // prepare data
      SetLength(aLeft, 4);
      aLeft[0].DataID := 1; aLeft[0].DataName := 'One';
      aLeft[1].DataID := 2; aLeft[1].DataName := 'Three';
      aLeft[2].DataID := 3; aLeft[2].DataName := 'Six';
      aLeft[3].DataID := 4; aLeft[3].DataName := 'Eight';
      SetLength(aRight, 6);
      aRight[0].DataID := 1; aRight[0].DataName := 'One';
      aRight[1].DataID := 2; aRight[1].DataName := 'Two';
      aRight[2].DataID := 3; aRight[2].DataName := 'Four';
      aRight[3].DataID := 4; aRight[3].DataName := 'Five';
      aRight[4].DataID := 5; aRight[4].DataName := 'Seven';
      aRight[5].DataID := 6; aRight[5].DataName := 'Eight';

      // do the magic - prepare control array
      SetLength(aCtrl, 8);
      aCtrl[0].Side := sBoth; aCtrl[0].Idx_L := 0; aCtrl[0].Idx_R := 0;
      aCtrl[1].Side := sRight; aCtrl[1].Idx_R := 1;
      aCtrl[2].Side := sLeft; aCtrl[2].Idx_L := 1;
      aCtrl[3].Side := sRight; aCtrl[3].Idx_R := 2;
      aCtrl[4].Side := sRight; aCtrl[4].Idx_R := 3;
      aCtrl[5].Side := sLeft; aCtrl[5].Idx_L := 2;
      aCtrl[6].Side := sRight; aCtrl[6].Idx_R := 4;
      aCtrl[7].Side := sBoth; aCtrl[7].Idx_L := 3; aCtrl[7].Idx_R := 5;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i, vIndex: integer;
    begin
      PrepareData;


      { prepare arrays based on Control array
      Loop through Control array and fill temp arrays from Left or Right arrays }
      SetLength(aLeft_tmp, 0);
      SetLength(aRight_tmp, 0);
      SetLength(aLeft_tmp, Length(aCtrl));
      SetLength(aRight_tmp, Length(aCtrl));
      vIndex := 0;
      for i := 0 to High(aCtrl) do
      begin
        if aCtrl[i].Side = sBoth then // Data from Both
        begin
          aLeft_tmp[vIndex] := aLeft[aCtrl[i].Idx_L];
          aRight_tmp[vIndex] := aRight[aCtrl[i].Idx_R];
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
        if aCtrl[i].Side = sLeft then // Data from Left side
        begin
          aLeft_tmp[vIndex] := aLeft[aCtrl[i].Idx_L];
          aRight_tmp[vIndex].BlankLine := true;
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
        if aCtrl[i].Side = sRight then // Data from Right side
        begin
          aRight_tmp[vIndex] := aRight[aCtrl[i].Idx_R];
          aLeft_tmp[vIndex].BlankLine := true;
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
      end;

      // Assign aligned data to main arrays
      aLeft := aLeft_tmp;
      aRight := aRight_tmp;
    end;
```

As I use the same or similar code for a lot of arrays, I'm trying to refactor and simplify it with `AlignArrays` function:

```
    procedure AlignArrays(vCtrl: TArray<TCtrlData>; var vLeft, vRight: TArray<TData>);
    var
      i, vIndex: integer;
      vLeft_tmp, vRight_tmp: TArray<TData>;
    begin
      SetLength(vLeft_tmp, Length(vCtrl));
      SetLength(vRight_tmp, Length(vCtrl));
      vIndex := 0;

     { prepare arrays based on Control array
      Loop through Control array and fill temp arrays from Left or Right arrays }
      for i := 0 to High(vCtrl) do
      begin
        if vCtrl[i].Side = sBoth then // Data from Both
        begin
          vLeft_tmp[vIndex] := vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L];
          vRight_tmp[vIndex] := vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R];
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
        if vCtrl[i].Side = sLeft then // Data from Left side
        begin
          vLeft_tmp[vIndex] := vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L];
          vRight_tmp[vIndex].BlankLine := true;
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
        if vCtrl[i].Side = sRight then // Data from Right side
        begin
          vRight_tmp[vIndex] := vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R];
          vLeft_tmp[vIndex].BlankLine := true;
          Inc(vIndex);
        end;
      end;

      vLeft := vLeft_tmp;
      vRight := vRight_tmp;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i, vIndex: integer;
    begin
      PrepareData;

      AlignArrays(aCtrl, aLeft, aRight);

    end;
```

**Question: Can this be better refactored and is it possible to work on the arrays without temp arrays?**

**EDIT:**

From comments and answers it seems I waste too much time preparing MCVE, I should better explain the problem I have. But, from an CleoR's answer I got an idea to align arrays by starting in he last line and aligning to the top. Adn it seems to work, and here is why: 
Because control array has instructions on how to align lines, I know exactly what the size of arrays is. And since aligning means 'stretchin' array/inserting new blank lines where needed, if I start from the bottom up, I don't need to insert anything, only move the lines that need to be moved.

Simple and it works - without temp arrays:

```
procedure AlignArraysBackwards(vCtrl: TArray<TCtrlData>; var vLeft, vRight: TArray<TData>);
var
  i: integer;
  vBlankRecord:TData;
begin

  // set blank record to blank out the moved line
  vBlankRecord.DataID:=0;
  vBlankRecord.DataName:='';
  vBlankRecord.BlankLine:=True;

  // set lenght for arrays
  SetLength(vLeft, Length(vCtrl));
  SetLength(vRight, Length(vCtrl));

  // align - starting from the bottom up
  for i := High(vCtrl) downto 0 do
  begin
    if vCtrl[i].Side = sBoth then // Data from Both
    begin
      // move Left line
      vLeft[i] := vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L];
      // blank out the line we just moved
      if vCtrl[i].Idx_L<>i then vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L]:=vBlankRecord;
      // move Rigth line
      vRight[i] := vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R];
      // blank out the line we copied from
      if vCtrl[i].Idx_R<>i then vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R]:=vBlankRecord;
    end;
    if vCtrl[i].Side = sLeft then // Data from Left side
    begin
      // move Left line
      vLeft[i] := vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L];
      // blank out the line we just moved
      if vCtrl[i].Idx_L<>i then  vLeft[vCtrl[i].Idx_L]:=vBlankRecord;
      // blank Right line
      vRight[i].BlankLine := true;
    end;
    if vCtrl[i].Side = sRight then // Data from Right side
    begin
      // move Left line
      vRight[i] := vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R];
      // blank out the line we just moved
      if vCtrl[i].Idx_R<>i then  vRight[vCtrl[i].Idx_R]:=vBlankRecord;
      // blank Left line
      vLeft[i].BlankLine := true;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Okay I think I can help you even more, could you just clarify one thing for me. Are the arrays aligned based on the smallest element in each array or just 1?

Comment: Okay I rewrote it in Delphi, let me know how it works

Comment: I created the whole MCVE for this reason - to not try to help me align the content, but help me improve my code as it was inefficient with temp arrays. The arrays are aligned by the control array - as they can contain simple strings, as in example and, in no sorted order at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Changed the solution to pseudocode.

You don't need a temp array, you can do it in place.

Lets assume the left and right arrays have enough space and they are the same size.

For each array you'll need to keep track of the last element in the array. Lets call this the dataPointer. Reverse loop over the arrays with a counter called endPointer.

1. At each step in the loop check if array[dataPointer] == endPointer + minElement for both arrays.
2. If true, array[endPointer] = endPointer + minElement and decrement the dataPointer.
3. If false, array[endPointer] = skip_value.
4. Do this until endPointer goes past the beginning of the array.

   ```
   skip_value = 0

   //Handles our assumptions.
   function setup(left,right)
       left.sort()
       right.sort()
       ldPointer = len(left)-1
       rdPointer = len(right)-1
       maxElement = max(left[ldPointer],right[rdPointer])
       //This is 1 in your examples. You can hard code this number.
       minElement = min(left[0],right[0])
       padLength = maxElement - minElement + 1
       pad(left,padLength)
       pad(right,padLength)
       return ldPointer,rdPointer,minElement

   //Aligns the arrays.
   function align(left,right)
       ldPointer,rdPointer,minElement = setup(left,right)
       for endPointer = len(left)-1; endPointer >= 0; i--
           //Look at the left element.
           if left[ldPointer] == endPointer+minElement
               left[endPointer] = endPointer+minElement
               ldPointer = ldPointer - 1
           else
               left[endPointer] = skip_value
           //Look at the right element.
           if right[rdPointer] == endPointer+minElement
               right[endPointer] = endPointer+minElement
               rdPointer = rdPointer - 1
           else
               right[endPointer] = skip_value
   ```

In case you want to try the algorithm out for yourself, heres a link to the repo. https://github.com/cleor41/StackOverflow_AlignArrays.

I don't know an ounce of Delphi but I tried to write it in Delphi so maybe you can understand it better. I also don't understand the need to have the  control array.

```
procedure AlignArraysBackwards(var vLeft, vRight: TArray<TData>);
var
  endPointer: Integer;
  vBlankRecord: TData;
  // Assumes the arrays have at least 1 element
  ldPointer: Length(vLeft)-1;
  rdPointer: Length(vRight)-1;
  maxElement: Max(vLeft[ldPointer].DataID,vRight[rdPointer].DataID);
  // Set this to 1 if arrays should always be 1 alligned
  // Else it aligns arrays starting from the array with the smallest value.
  minElement: Min(vLeft[0].DataID,vRight[0].DataID);
  padLength: maxElement - minElement + 1;
begin

  // set blank record to blank out the moved line
  vBlankRecord.DataID:=0;
  vBlankRecord.DataName:='';
  vBlankRecord.BlankLine:=True;

  // set length for arrays
  SetLength(vLeft, padLength);
  SetLength(vRight, padLength);

  // align - starting from the bottom up
  for endPointer := High(vLeft) downto 0 do
  begin
    // Start Left array
    if vLeft[ldPointer].DataID = endPointer + minElement
    then
      begin
        vLeft[endPointer] := vLeft[ldPointer];
        ldPointer := ldPointer - 1;
      end
    else
      begin
        vLeft[endPointer] := vBlankRecord;
      end;
    // End Left Array
    // Start Right array
    if vRight[rdPointer].DataID = endPointer + minElement
    then
      begin
        vRight[endPointer] := vRight[rdPointer];
        rdPointer := rdPointer - 1;
      end
    else
      begin
        vRight[endPointer] := vBlankRecord;
      end;
    // End Right Array
  end;
end;
```

Comment: True, but it also presents a very large amount of irrelevant GUI code. This is really an algo question and pseudo code will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, don't really understand your pseudo code, don't know Phyton... BUT! you gave me an idea: **align arrays with backwards loop**. (it might be that this is what your example shows, but I don't really see it).

Comment: See my progress in EDIT.

Comment: I changed it to pseudocode but it looks like you got the right idea! You have to go over the array backwards and compare the element to the loop counter + "some number". The arrays don't have to interact at all. You just need to use both arrays to figure out the value of "some number" and to expand the arrays to the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method that will insert the records in the array or (as in my sample) you can use generics (TList).

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Generics.Collections;

type
  TData = record
    DataID: integer;
    DataName: string;
    BlankLine: boolean;
    // I add this function to make it make the code easier to read
    class function New(const DataID: integer; DataName: string;
      BlankLine: boolean = false): TData; static;
  end;

var
  aLeft, aRight: TList<TData>;

  { TData }

class function TData.New(const DataID: integer; DataName: string;
  BlankLine: boolean = false): TData;
begin
  result.DataID := DataID;
  result.DataName := DataName;
  result.BlankLine := BlankLine;
end;

procedure AllignData;
var
  n: word;
begin
  n := 0;
  repeat
    if (n < aRight.Count) and (n < aLeft.Count) then
    begin
      if aLeft[n].DataID < aRight[n].DataID then
        aRight.Insert(n, TData.New(aLeft[n].DataID, '', true))
      else if aLeft[n].DataID > aRight[n].DataID then
        aLeft.Insert(n, TData.New(aRight[n].DataID, '', true));
      // if they are equlal, we skip the line
      // you wish to use an array instead, write a function inserting data item in it
    end
    else
    begin
      if n < aLeft.Count then
        aRight.Add(TData.New(aRight[n].DataID, '', true));
      if n < aRight.Count then
        aLeft.Add(TData.New(aRight[n].DataID, '', true));
    end;

    inc(n);
  until (n >= aRight.Count) and (n >= aLeft.Count);
end;

procedure OutputData;
var
  n: word;
  sl, sr: string;
begin
  n := 0;
  repeat
    if n < aLeft.Count then
      sl := aLeft[n].DataName
    else
      sl := '';
    if n < aRight.Count then
      sr := aRight[n].DataName
    else
      sr := '';

    writeln(sl: 15, sr: 15);
    inc(n);
  until (n >= aRight.Count) and (n >= aLeft.Count);
end;

begin
  // Initialize the data
  aLeft := TList<TData>.Create;
  aRight := TList<TData>.Create;
  try
    aLeft.Add(TData.New(1, 'One'));
    aLeft.Add(TData.New(3, 'Three'));
    aLeft.Add(TData.New(6, 'Six'));
    aLeft.Add(TData.New(8, 'Eight'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(1, 'One'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(2, 'Two'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(4, 'Four'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(5, 'Five'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(7, 'Seven'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(8, 'Eight'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(9, 'Nine'));
    aRight.Add(TData.New(10, 'Ten'));
    // Do the output and processing
    OutputData;
    // I assume that the arrays (lists) have been sorted
    AllignData;
    writeln;
    OutputData
  finally
    aLeft.Free;
    aRight.Free;
  end;
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: Your function named `Create` reads at the call site like a constructor. Which makes one wonder why you don't have to destroy the object. In my view it's better to use a name other than `Create` for a static function that returns a value type. Personally I use `New` for such a function, but there are other conventions in use.

Comment: You still use the word `Create` there which makes me think of a constructor. FWIW, Emba do this too and I think it causes a lot of confusion. I'm thinking of the record constructors named `Create` that you find in the RTTI and regex libs. Ah, now you edit further. I like having a single name for such methods. No need to repeat anything to do with the type since you always write it as `TData.XXX` and therefore include the type.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but not sure I want to use TList - see my progress in EDIT of question.

Comment: It seems like your example assumes the arrays are sorted by integers. Not exactly, as I have a control array that has already been created to correctly align arrays - that's why I used strings as example, to not assume integer sorted order. So, as I understand your code, it won't work on non-sorted strings, right?

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni Exactly. I did not invent anything and used data stated in your question. The data used for initialization of your array has been sorted. Do you have any problems with sorting data algorythms? I alligned the lists in the way given by you in your illustration. I do not see any sense in the control array as it contains excessive data that can be restored at any time from the main lists/arrays.

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni I do not see the problem  in converting my code to array. You just need to write a function inserting a member in the middle of it. Do you have problems with writing this function?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how can I join/improve my AlignArraysBackwards with your example, without TList.